# How to get records from select statement based on one column distinct value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, distinct

Please help me with next problem:

[image]

And the result should be:

[image]

filtered by iban_code distinct

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll want to clearly show example inputs and outputs, as text (not images, and especially not externally linked images). You'll want to add a clear description of the problem, what you're trying to do, and where you're having issues. Most importantly, you'll want to include what you've tried so far; we can't help you fix your issue if you don't present an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number` analytical function.

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
Row_number() 
 over (partition by per_id, iban_code 
        order by main_bank_account desc) as rn
From your_table t)
Where rn=1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.